# Bootstrap DatePicker change date format

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, date, datepicker, frontend

I have a Bootstrap DatePicker included in Inspinia Theme. Choosing dates from the picker itself works without issues. The dates have DD.MM.YYYY format.

Now if I want to type in a date without using the DatePicker in the European date format DD.MM.YYYY the DatePicker doesn't understand that and shows invalid date(e.g. when I type in 13.01.1997 because the format is MM.DD.YYYY so always month first) when clicking on the input once again.

Is there a way to configure/change the format of the DatePicker so that it understands custom Date inputs in such a format DD.MM.YYYY ?

[image: This is the input I want the DatePicker to underst]

[image: This is what the DatePicker]

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'dd.mm.yyyy'
 });
```

Comment: I have added this to my `head` already but it doesn't seem to help